# JMS Producer and Consumer taking too much time. Why?

Tags: java, jms

I have used JMS to receive async messages in queue then start consuming these messages as soon as message comes in queue.
For this i have Written producer and consumer code.
Everything is working fine but the entire process is taking too much time around 2-3 minutes for 10000 records.(i have used a loop just for simulation)
Below is the entire code:

This is JMS Producer:

```
public class JmsMessageProducer
{
    public void jmsListener(String obj) throws Exception 
    {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
        broker.start();
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        try
        {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            // Producer
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue3");
            
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer3"));
            connection.start();
            
            producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            
            for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
            {
                String payload = "Important Task"+i;
                Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
                
                
                
                System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
                
                producer.send(msg);
            }
            
            long millis2 = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            long millis3    =   millis2- millis;
            System.out.println("time taken: "+ millis3 );
            
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if(producer != null)
            {
                producer.close();
            }
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.close();
            }
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
            broker.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This is listener code:

```
public class ConsumerMessageListener implements MessageListener 
{ 
    private String consumerName;
    
    public ConsumerMessageListener(String consumerName) 
    {
        this.consumerName = consumerName;
    }
    
    DummyAdapter adapter    =   new DummyAdapter();
    public void onMessage(Message message) 
    {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try
        {           
            System.out.println(consumerName + " received "+ textMessage.getText());
        //  adapter.dummy(textMessage.getText());
        } 
        catch (JMSException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing this first time.
Can anyone tell me why is this process taking too much time?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the SLA that you are expecting, but your message Broker is working at the rate of 80 messages/sec (approx.), which is NOT bad.

And one issue with your code is `session.createProducer(queue)` is the problem for the time lag as it is a costly operation (takes time) and you can use a single producer object to produce multiple messages.

So create `MessageProducer` outside the for loop as shown below:

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    String payload = "Important Task"+i;
    Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);

   System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");

   producer.send(msg);
}
```

You have to `close` both `producer` and `session` objects in the `finally` block.

P.S.: Also, as a side note, it would be good if you name your producer `class` name as `JmsMessagePrducer` instead of `JmsMessageListener` as in general we use the name as `Listener` only for `JMS` consumers.

**UPDATE:**

> I just want to know that is it good to process around 80
>   messages/sec.? that too without any operation after consuming. What if
>   add more tasks after message consumption from queue, like inserting in
>   db or some business operation.

It is NOT wise to simply tell that 80 messages/sec is better or 50 messages/seconds is better without knowing which Server/OS/etc...(many parameters need to be considered). When it comes to performance requirements you need to specify/define the requirements first.

If your current code processes around 80 messages/sec, then that is what your application (test program) benchmark is, for the given conditions. So if you feel like it is NOT meeting your performance requirements, then you need to configure multiple JMS listeners to process messages parallelly and change your design.

Comment: Thanks for reply javaguy. I had updated my code as you suggested (As you can see in my question) , but it still taking long time. Can you please suggest anything else?

Comment: What is the SLA that you are expecting ?

Comment: I just want to know that is it good to process around 80 messages/sec.? that too without any operation after consuming. What if add more tasks after message consumption from queue, like inserting in db or some business operation.

Comment: ok i got what you want to say. I am running this entire setup locally. As i had already told that i am doing this first time so i was in doubt that my way of implementation is good or not? or by doing other way i can achieve it faster ? Anyway thank you for your time javaguy.